# Object not getting returned properly from Ionic service

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, ionic-framework

Background: I'm making a simple Ionic project about the NYC Subway. I am using the Ionic "tabs" template, and I have a tab that lists all of the routes with their symbols (1, 2, 3, A, C, E, etc.) and the user should be able to click on any of the routes listed there and be taken to a detail page (kind of like how they have a "Chats/Chat Detail" setup in the tabs template when you start a new ionic project).

The problem is I can't seem to get the Route Detail page to load information about the selected route. Expressions like `{{route.name}}` and `{{route.desc}}` come up blank.

routes.json file (sample, filed under `www/js/routes.json`):

```
{
  "routes": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1",
    "desc": "7 Avenue Local",
    "className": "c123"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "2",
    "desc": "7 Avenue Express",
    "className": "c123"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "3",
    "desc": "7 Avenue Express",
    "className": "c123"
  },
...
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

// ...

.state("tab.routes", {
  url: "/routes",
  views: {
    "tab-routes": {
      templateUrl: "templates/tab-routes.html",
      controller: "RoutesCtrl"
    }
  }
})
  .state("tab.route-detail", {
    url: "/routes/:id",
    views: {
      "tab-routes": {
        templateUrl: "templates/route-detail.html",
        controller: "RouteDetailCtrl"
      }
    }
  });
```

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

// ...

/* This one works perfectly */
.controller('RoutesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("js/routes.json").then(function(response) {
    $scope.routes = response.data.routes;

    console.log($scope.routes);
  });
})

/* This one does NOT work */
/* $stateParams.id returns the correct value, but $scope.route
        does not store the Route returned from the service (null) */
.controller("RouteDetailCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, Routes) {
  $scope.route = Routes.getRoute($stateParams.id);
})
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

/* This is the problem */
.factory("Routes", function($http) {
  return {
    getRoute: function(id) {
      return $http.get("js/routes.json").then(function(response) {
        var routes = response.data.routes;

        for(var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
          if(parseInt(id) === parseInt(routes[i].id)) {
            return routes[i];
          }
        }

        return null;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I think the problem has something to do with the way the JSON is coming back in `services.js` - is it the way my JSON is stored, or the way I'm "parsing" it on the receiving end? The "RoutesCtrl" works just fine, but I can't seem to get the route detail working no matter what variation of `response` I use in `services.js` - I have tried `response`, `response.data`, `response.data.routes`, nothing works.

route-detail.html: (as you can see, {{route.whatever}} refers to the $scope.route in `controllers.js` but it's not getting stored).

```
<ion-view view-title="{{route.name}}">
    <ion-content class="padding">

        <h2>{{route.name}}</h2>
        <h2>{{route.desc}}</h2>

        <p>This is the detail page.</p>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the routes object as the same code works fine in `RoutesCtrl` but with the way youare handling the response in `RouteDetailCtrl`. The response returned from `Route` service is **not an primitive javascript values but a promise** and you need to handle the promise correctly to get your response:

```
.controller("RouteDetailCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, Routes) {
   Routes.getRoute($stateParams.id)
     .then(function (response) {
        $scope.route = response;
     });
})
```